# stringByReplacingCharactersInRange Decreases NSString Length

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, nsstring

I'm somehow using stringByReplacingCharactersInRange incorrectly, but I can't understand how. My goal is to replace one character of an `NSString` with another. I do this many times but after two replacements it starts cutting from the end of the NSString, I don't want this. Here is my code.

```
    NSRange firstCharRange = NSMakeRange(mi, mi); // mi is an int, indicating the index of the replaced char

    myword = [myword stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:firstCharRange withString:bb.titleLabel.text]; // myword is the string
```

Initially, `myword` is @"RRRRRRRR", after replacing the first string it becomes

```
eRRRRRRR
```

then

```
egRRRRRR
```

then

```
eghRRRR // why did cut off the last character?
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second parameter of `NSMakeRange()` is a length, not the end index. You probably want to just pass in `1`.

Answer (score 0):

NSString *str =@"Hardeep_Singh";

```
NSLog(@"Before = %@",str);

str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"_" withString:@" "];

NSLog(@"After = %@",str);
```

You can use it.In this We can replace one Character with another charater of a NSString. 
May be it's helpful for you.

```
NSString *myword=[NSString stringWithString:@"0123456789"];

NSLog(@"Before = %@ ",myword);

NSRange firstCharRange = NSMakeRange(1,2);
```

// Frist argument is start point and second is end point it's star from 0 and so on.

```
myword = [myword stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:firstCharRange withString:@"H"];

NSLog(@"After = %@ ",myword);
```

It's your ans may be your under stand it.